# Cannot install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.04

I am currently using Windows 8 Pro. Now I want to install Ubuntu too. I have a bootable disk containing Ubuntu and my system is booting from that disk properly. But the problem is while installing Ubuntu. Everything is working fine until I reach the page saying 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows'. When I press the continue button from that page the installing process ends without any reason. A black screen appears, "terminated by signal 15" and "speech dispatch error" messages are shown on the black screen. Then my disk gets ejected automatically and when I press enter key the system restarts by loading Windows. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bought the machine with Windows 8 from an OEM (e.g. Samsung, Asus, HP etc.) it has secure boot enabled which prevents installing different OS definitions in the boot area. (EFI).

How to disable secure boot depends on your machine, but i suggest to take a good look around the bios and search for secureboot, secure boot, prevent installation, KI, MSK or similar.

Comment: Well... I checked it. My system was not bought from an OEM. It is an assembled one. Secure boot is also disabled. So what should I do now ?

Comment: try running the installation in advanced mode (text). This should provide a bit more options and more clearer indication where it fails. Another option is to try to do manually the required steps (grub-install, grub-setup, etc.) this should be helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Thanks... I will try the advanced mode. When I tried to install the last time "Speech dispatcher disabled" error was found. I  am not sure whether it's an error or not. I just found it on the black screen. Why is it so ?

Comment: I tried the advanced mode too. But nothing happened. It's the same old error."speed dispatcher disabled" error is still showing. With it on the black screen I saw "terminated by signal 15". What is it ?